# MySql count with like query is very slow response

Tags: mysql

Below is my query, query is very slow and I tried to set some index but indexes are not working. Table has almost 150000 rows. Please help me out.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM attachment
    LEFT JOIN candidate ON attachment.data_item_id = candidate.candidate_id 
        AND attachment.data_item_type = 100 
        AND attachment.site_id = candidate.site_id
    LEFT JOIN USER AS owner_user ON candidate.owner = owner_user.user_id
WHERE attachment.RESUME = 1 
AND attachment.data_item_id != 0 
AND( (attachment.text LIKE '%java%') ) 
AND( ISNULL(candidate.is_admin_hidden) OR(candidate.is_admin_hidden = 0) ) 
AND( ISNULL(candidate.is_active) OR(candidate.is_active = 1) ) 
AND attachment.site_id = 1
```

Index for attachment table

[image: Index for attachment table]

Index for candidate table

[image: Index for candidate table]

Comment: Just a guess, but you may have slightly **over done** the indexing

Comment: Why do you need an index on all of this stuff? First name? Is it to look up all the people named Bob? Indexing by `email1,email2` is actually quite useless. It doesn't allow quick searching of either, it allows searching by `email1` and then if there's a match on those, easy searching of `email2`.

Comment: Tip: Have boolean columns that can't be `NULL`. This avoids the `ISNULL()` mess. Remember: MySQL does table scans when it can't find a matching index. **Table scans are often ridiculously slow**. Use `EXPLAIN` to find out what's going on.

Comment: `column LIKE '%pattern%'` is always fullscan and, hence, slow. None index can help. Recommendation - create subquery with all conditions except `(attachment.text LIKE '%java%')`, apply this condition in outer query. The less percent of rows selected by subquery the more query improvement.

Comment: All problem in like query, no indexing working so how can i speed up with like query ?

Comment: I have described possible way to some improvement already. Have you tested it?

Comment: I'm not able to create sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `LEFT` necessary?  What is the intent of `AND  a.data_item_type = 100` *in an ON*?  It sounds like a "filter", which should be in the `WHERE`.

The indexes are thwarted by allowing (and testing for) both `NULL` and `0`.  Pick one, then code accordingly.  If you keep NULL instead of 0, express it this way:  `candidate.is_active IS NULL`.

Or...  Is this `ISNULL(candidate.is_admin_hidden)` testing whether the `LEFT` failed to find a row instead of checking the column itself?

Remove the Join to `owner_user`, it seems to be doing nothing (other than slowing down the query).

Rarely is a "prefix" index (eg, `skills(255)`) useful.

The only practical use for `INDEX(..., email1, email2, ...)` is if you will be testing *both* emails for [different] values.

**More**

Composite index:

```
attachment: INDEX(site_id, RESUME)  -- in either order
candidate:  INDEX(site_id, candidate_id, is_active, is_admin_hidden, owner)
owner_user: INDEX(user_id)  -- unless it is the PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Resume in attachment table. I removed join but still speed is slow so any guess what should index columns.

Comment: @AshishNishad - I made several changes/additions.  The intent of `LEFT` may impact some of my answer.